# Existe alguma diferença entre a visibilidade de uma view View.GONE ou false?

Tags: java, android

Eu gostaria de saber para qual dessas implementações é a correta?

```
tlb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

ou

```
tlb.setVisibility(false);
```

Qual a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Com setVisibility( false ) o objeto não aparece, mas fica o espaço vazio na tela, enquanto setVisibility( View.GONE ) não deixa espaço vazio.

Comment: uia!!!Somente isso? Entendi. Então eu devo preferir o Gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme a  [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) , o método `setVisibility` solicita um `int`, e não um `boolean`!

Você pode usar três opções:

1. [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)   (Sendo exibido)
2. [View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (Não é exibido mas ocupa o espaço em tela)
3. [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)       (Não é exibido e não ocupa o espaço em tela)

Acredito que se tentar passar um `boolean` neste método, deverá ocorrer o seguinte erro:

> Error:: no suitable method found for
>   setVisibility(boolean) method View.setVisibility(int) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; boolean cannot be converted to int)
>   method ImageView.setVisibility(int) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; boolean cannot be converted to int) method
>   VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility(int) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; boolean cannot be converted to int)

Comment: nossa como eu sou idiota. Entendi!!!

Comment: eu curti o INVISIBLE. Porque eu posso setar para ele aparecer depois e ele nao fica torto na tela caso precise aparecer...

Answer (score 4):

A propriedade `Gone` faz com que a view seja tratada como se não existisse enquanto o `Invisible` ele simplesmente esta invisível, então sim tem diferença.

Comment: não entendi.....

Comment: mas se não existe e se não está visível tem diferença?

Comment: Tem porque se ela esta invisível você pode alinhar e posicionar outra view com base nessa invisível, agora se ela não existe você não consegue fazer isso. É mais para questões de alinhamento  e visuais mesmo.