# Android Studio ScrollView - Existe alguma maneira de Modificar o tamanho via codigo?

Tags: java, android

A dúvida é o seguinte... Tenho um Vertical ScrollView com 20 botões posicionados em 5x2 na view, quando uso o scroll vejo os outros 10 botões que estão escondidos, porém esses botões ficam invisíveis caso não tenha funções definidas no select do banco que uso pra popular os botões... Ai vem o grande problema, o scrollView ainda rola ate o ultimo botão mesmo que este esteja invisível, tem alguma forma de não deixar rolar além dos botões q estão visíveis?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dev_03.sabbemobile.Telas.Pedidos.BarRestaurante.FastFood.FastFoodPedidos.FastFoodPedidoActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrTabRef1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Sobremesas"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Bebidas"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrTabRef1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="195dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView17">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr1"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr2"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr3"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr4"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr3"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr5"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr6"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr7"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr8"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr9"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr8"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr10"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr9"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr11"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr12"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr11"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr13"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr12"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr14"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr13"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr15"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr14"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr16"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr11"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr17"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr16"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr18"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr13"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr17"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr19"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr14"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr18"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr20"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr15"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrRfr19"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrTabRef2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm1"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm2"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm3"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm4"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm3"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm5"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm6"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm7"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm8"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm9"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm8"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm10"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm9"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm11"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm12"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm11"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm13"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm12"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm14"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm13"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm15"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm14"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm16"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm11"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm17"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm16"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm18"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm13"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm17"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm19"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm14"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm18"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm20"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm15"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTabRfrSbm19"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrFinalizar"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
    android:text="Finalizar Pedido"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTabRfrVoltar"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
    android:text="Voltar"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

```
    //TODO DECLARAÇÃO DOS BOTÕES REFRI
    btnRefri[0] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr1);
    btnRefri[1] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr2);
    btnRefri[2] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr3);
    btnRefri[3] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr4);
    btnRefri[4] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr5);
    btnRefri[5] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr6);
    btnRefri[6] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr7);
    btnRefri[7] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr8);
    btnRefri[8] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr9);
    btnRefri[9] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr10);
    btnRefri[10] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr11);
    btnRefri[11] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr12);
    btnRefri[12] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr13);
    btnRefri[13] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr14);
    btnRefri[14] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr15);
    btnRefri[15] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr16);
    btnRefri[16] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr17);
    btnRefri[17] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr18);
    btnRefri[18] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr19);
    btnRefri[19] = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTabRfrRfr20);
    btnRefri[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[3].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[4].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[5].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[6].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[7].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[8].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[9].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[10].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[11].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[12].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[13].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[14].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[15].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[16].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[17].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[18].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[19].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnRefri[0].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[1].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[2].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[3].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[4].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[5].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[6].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[7].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[8].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[9].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[10].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[11].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[12].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[13].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[14].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[15].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[16].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[17].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[18].setClickable(false);
    btnRefri[19].setClickable(       
    PopulaBtnRefri();
    PopulaBtnSobreMesa();

    return rootView;
}
public void PopulaBtnRefri() {
    try {
        gpConn = new GruposProd(getContext());
        Cursor cursor;
        db = gpConn.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT DESCRICAO_RESUMIDA, CODINTERNOPRODUTO, CODGRUPO FROM PRODUTO_FINAL " +
                "INNER JOIN PRODUTO_ACOMP ON PRODUTO_ACOMP.BEBIDA = 'S' WHERE CODINTERNOPRODUTO = PRODUTO_ACOMP.CODACOMP", null);
        int i = 0;
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                refri[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DESCRICAO_RESUMIDA"));
                btnRefri[i].setText(refri[i]);
                btnRefri[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnRefri[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                btnRefri[i].setTextSize(12);
                btnRefri[i].setClickable(true);
                i++;
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("btnRefri", "erro", e);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Cadê o código chefe?!

Comment: não sei postar ele formatado aqui =(

Comment: Pronto, parte do código ta ai, pelo menos o que é importante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de usar:

```
btnRefri[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Use:

```
btnRefri[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179248/35406) do [Thiago Luiz Domacoski](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25969/thiago-luiz-domacoski) mais detalhes em relação a diferença entre `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE` e `GONE`.

> - [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) (Sendo exibido)
> - [View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (Não é exibido mas ocupa o espaço em tela)
> - [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) (Não é exibido e não ocupa o espaço em tela)

E [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179242/35406):

> A propriedade *Gone* faz com que a *view* seja tratada como se não
>   existisse enquanto o *Invisible* ele simplesmente esta invisível, então
>   sim tem diferença.

Comment: Resolveu, muitíssimo obrigado..... Solução simples e direta!!!!! VALEEEEU

Comment: @MarcioVieira se quiser validar a resposta, fique a vontade. =D

Comment: não sei como faz isso kkkkkkkk, até quero

Comment: @MarcioVieira achou até rápido. ehuhe.. boa sorte ai.